# Bidirectionnal iterator over a TreeMap[A,B]

Tags: java, scala, iterator, bidirectional

Is there a way to get a bidirectionnal iterator over a `TreeMap`, ie an `iterator[(A,B)]` with `hasPrevious`, `previous` methods completing the `hasNext`, `next` methods ?

I know it does not exists natively in scala but I have some hope some trick could make it possible via some java adapters/facade/wrappers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) provides the [navigableKeySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#navigableKeySet%28%29) method which returns a [NavigableSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) which provides a [descendingIterator()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#descendingIterator%28%29).

Not certain how you would work with that in `Scala` though.

Comment: sorry, I was not clear enough : scala does not implement this feature. But yes, your link is correct ! I removed my comment.